# Translating overhead digit in UPC barcode

Tags: vb6, ascii, barcode

I've inherited the source to a legacy VB6 barcode library with no documentation. My understanding is it translates an 11-digit number to UPC barcode (I hope I have that right, it might be EAN-8).

As far as I can tell, the check digit (right-most trailing number) is calculating correctly, buy the overhead digit (left-most leading number) is not.

The digit is translated by converting the first digit in the source number to a corresponding ASCII value. 1 becomes `Chr(34)`, 2 becomes `Chr(35)` and so on. The problem is 6 and 0 (zero). I guess 6 should be `Chr(39)` (apostrophe), but the barcode doesn't scan. I'm not sure what zero should be. I've tried both `Chr(33)` (exclamation) and `Chr(45)` (dash) and barcodes scan for neither. All other translated digits scan fine.

I'm hoping someone has either done this before and know what these should be, or knows a reference on the web. I've tried Googling, but all I can find is the general format of the barcode and how to calculate the check digit, but nothing on translating the overhead digit.

**Edit 1:** for what it's worth, I've also seen this digit refered to as a type digit and inidcator digit.

**Edit 2:** this is actually a bad question on my part because I didn't know what I was asking. Turns out 1) I was working with a specific commercial barcode font, and 2) I needed more than the overhead digit. I answered my own question with what I was able to find, but in all honesty my answer turns out to have very little to do with my question after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the real problem wasn't so much the algorithm (though it was incorrect) but that this library was written specifically for use with [Wasp](http://www.waspbarcode.com) barcode fonts. What I was really needing was how to create the mechanical output that would then be rendered as a valid barcode by the font.

After much digging, I was able to find [this page](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~BarCodeThings). Though written in Visual FoxPro, I was able to translate it to VB6 to create the algorithm I needed.

Comment: I ended up creating my own code to generate barcode images rather than relying on fonts, so that I wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, I've never done anything like this, but I have pretty good google skills. [This page](http://www.idautomation.com/fonts/upc-ean/faq.html) looks like it has some pretty complete information. The table listing the UPC / EAN guard patterns and special characters do not agree with yours though so you'll have to let me know if this was any help or a waste of time.
[image]

Comment: A good start, but unfortunately incomplete for my needs. Turns out I needed character codes for the barcode glyphs as well for a particular commercial barcode font. Please see my answer for more info if interested.